# Ember.js index not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ember.js

I am attempting to create an Ember.js SPA within an ASP.NET MVC5 application. I am using the sample project provided at the weblink below. In it, I have created a new index.cshtml along with application.js and routes.js file. However, the handlebars template is not executing. Below is my code. Does anyone know why this is not working?

All I want is for the menu with the About text to display and for me to click on the About link and see the text "About this app....". Currently, All I see is the text "Test About", so I am inclined to believe that the implementation is done correctly.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn463786.aspx

**EfaAppTabs.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>    
    <h1>Test About</h1>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="EfaEmberApp-1.0.0">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h1>Movies</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="well">
                <div class="navbar navbar-static-top">
                    <div class="navbar-inner">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                            <li>{{#linkTo 'about'}}About{{/linkTo}} </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    {{outlet}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <p>&copy;2018 EFA</p>
        </div>
    </script>


    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="about">
        <div class="container"></div>
        <h3>About this app...</h3>
    </script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery-ui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ember")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Efa")
</body>
</html>
```

**EfaEmberApp-1.0.0.js**

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();
```

**EfaEmberRoutes-1.0.0.js**

```
// Routes
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.route('about');
});
```

Comment: that template is *very* outdated. I can just recommend you to not use it.

Comment: @Lux Ok. Is there something else you can recommend as an alternative?

Comment: keep your asp.net backend separated from your ember app. use `ember-cli` for ember development. this is the only sane choice.

Comment: @Lux. Thank you for the quick response. Can you recommend any online resources or tutorials that can show me how to do this?

Comment: the [official guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/) are the best place to start. for interactive discussion maybe join the discussion forum and the slack channel both listed [here](https://emberjs.com/community/).

Comment: @Lux. Thank you. Final question, will the CLI-created SPA integrate with my existing ASP.NET MVC application (created in VS2013)? If no, are there any other SPA oriented front-end frameworks that can be developed in Visual Studio? I ask because I already have the M and C of MVC taken care of. I just need the V.

Comment: maybe you should discuss this in a more chatty way (hint: slack). but if you choose an SPA you always separate your client and your backend. asp.NET MVC will work well as backend for ember. Also visual studio code is a great IDE for ember. However the fact that you use an SPA means always its more then the `V` of a server MVC framework. Usually you integrate them after your final build for deployment.